# gitignore - how to ignore .idea/ directory for rubymine

Tags: git, gitignore

I've placed .idea/ in both my `~/.gitignore_global` and in my projects specific `.gitignore` file (and committed the later) but I still see the file as unstaged.

How can I really ignore these files?

I've done this:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

but it didn't help.

the filename is ok:

```
$ ls ~/.gitignore_global
/home/durrantm/.gitignore_global
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These files are added into the git repository already. Do the `git rm --cached .idea` then commit.

Comment: Just one note, to recursively remove files add -r option. `git rm -r --cached .idea`.

Comment: For those who do not know, 'recursively' means the removal of folders as well - the file hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also have to run a filter-branch, to completely wipe out the folder of your entire repository. On github you'll find a handy documentation for that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git update-index --assume-unchanged`